# Binary Division

Tags: divisibility, binary

IF I convert the dividend and divisor into decimal, perform the division and convert the remainder and quotient back in to binary will I get correct answer?
I'm doing this:

- $630 ÷ 13$
- Quotient=$48= (110000)_2$
- Remainder=$6= (110)_2$

But if I use this online calculator [here](http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=1001110110&den=1101&f=d&e=1&m=1), I get

- Quotient=$(1111110)_2$
- Remainder=$0$

So my question is what is the correct way to perform binary division, the exclusive-or operator one or by simply subtracting the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that "it depends".

If your binary numbers are integers, then the first result is correct:
$$
630=48\cdot13+6,
$$
so the integer part of the quotient is, indeed, 48 and the remainder is six.

The link that you gave specifically states that it is doing *polynomial division*.
What that means is that it interprets the individual bits as coefficients of powers of $x$ in such a way that the least signficant bit are the lower degree terms. This polynomial is an element of the ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. In this case it interprets
$$
630=1001110110_2=x^9+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2+x
$$
and
$$
13=1101_2=x^3+x^2+1.
$$
This time it happens that the polynomial division has zero remainder, and the output is that the quotient is $111110_2=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$. Let's check:
$$
\begin{align}
(x^3+x^2+1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x)&=x^3(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x)+\\
&+x^2(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x)+\\
&+1(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x)\\
&=x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+\\
&+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+\\
&+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x\\
&=x^9+2x^8+2x^7+3x^6+3x^5+3x^4+2x^3+x^2+x\\
&=x^9+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2+x,
\end{align}
$$
because the arithmetic of the coefficients of the polynomials is done modulo two.

The latter type of division is very important to mast for example when CRC-checks are tagged to data blocks.

So the answer depends on how your sequence of bits should be interpreted.

Comment: The polynomial option would give the same results. Clever .;) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The calculator you posted does not do operations in the usual sense, it does it in $GF(2)$, i.e. modulo 2, in each coordinate  $1+1=0$, for example.

Arithmetic should give the same answer when done in base 10 and base 2.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you should get the correct result.  Note that both the first and second subtraction they subtract $1001_2-1101_2=100_2$  They must be working in the field of two elements, not in $\Bbb N$